# Correct way to call asynchronous method from synchronous

Tags: asynchronous, task, synchronous

Good afternoon.

I looked at many articles on this topic, one still has no complete understanding.

I have an asynchronous method, for example:

```
public Task<Customer> Get(int id)
{
    return await client.GetCustomer(id);
}
```

I have a synchronous method that should call an asynchronous method, for example:

```
public Order GetOrder()
{
   //Invoking Asynchronous Method and Defining Customer Variable
   
   return new Order { Customer = customer};
}
```

**Question:**
What is the best way to make this call?

P.S.
There are the following ways:

1.First way

```
var customer = Get(10).Result;
```

2.Second way

```
var customer = Get(10).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

3.Third way

```
var customer = Task.Run(async()=>await Get(10)).Result;
```

4.Fourth way - Apply the RunSync method of the AsyncHelper class ([AsyncHelper from Microsoft](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/AsyncHelper.cs))

```
var customer  = AsyncHelper.RunSync(()=>Get(10));
```

Note - here under the hood creation and execution of Task

5.The fifth way - Apply the Run method of the AsyncContext class library Nito.AsyncEx

```
var customer  = AsyncContext.Run(()=>Get(10));
```

**I would like to get a short and reasoned answer.**